# How to get more than 1000 objects from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I have around 300K objects on s3 and I need to fetch all of them, based on the documentation it states that only the first 1000 objects will be returned. How can I accomplish this using Go?. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
// Get the list of items
resp, err := s3svc.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
    Bucket:  aws.String(Bucket),
    Prefix:  aws.String(Prefix),
})
if err != nil {
    exitErrorf("Unable to list items in bucket %q, %v", Bucket, err)
}

for _, item := range resp.Contents {
    // Store data
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this post received negative votes. This is a good question and the answer is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 10):

Use the continuation token  to iterate through all objects:

```
var continuationToken *string
for {
    resp, err := u.s3.ListObjectsV2(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket:  aws.String(Bucket),
        Prefix:  aws.String(Prefix),
        ContinuationToken: continuationToken,
    })
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to list items in bucket %q, %v", Bucket, err)
    }
    for _, item := range resp.Contents {
         // process each object.
    }
    if !aws.BoolValue(resp.IsTruncated) {
        break
    }
    continuationToken = resp.NextContinuationToken
}
```